# How do I debug ExtJS 4 app without building every time?

Tags: extjs

We have an ExtJS 4.2.1 app and use sencha cmd to build.

But during development I don't want to build every time I change something in the code.

But the index HTML file has bootstrap code in it and the locations of images, other js libraries, etc. is different pre and post build.

Also, even the "testing" concatenated code it too long to set break points in firebug.

So how can I run the code and set break points without building every time.

Typically we just run the code files themselves, but as I said, the location in the source tree, and the index.html file has bootstrap code, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is include css and js libraries BOTH as single files and through the bootstrap. Since they have different paths they won't load twice. The extjs library is loaded through proper setup of the main application class and the loader.

When you're ready for production you can manually remove those since they'll fail every time. Our you can play with the directives. I believe anything included in `<x-bootstrap>` is ignored.

From the documentation:. The compiler ignores the files in the x-bootstrap block, and they are removed from the final page, as we will see later.